# How can I insert content into the blank space at the top of a v-data-table in its mobile version?

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I was using v-data-table, and when it switches to the mobile version, it leaves a blank space at the top automatically. I attempted to add content directly within that space.

I'm using Vuetify2.

[image]

```
<thead class="v-data-table-header v-data-table-header-mobile">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="v-data-table-header-mobile__wrapper">
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Specifically, I wanted to include the text "Announce" above the table, but I encountered an issue where the blank space remained.

**My question is: How can I insert content or text directly into that blank space?**

```
<v-data-table
  :loading="loading"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
  disable-sort
  hide-default-footer
  class="elevation-1 mt-4 pt-4"
>
  <template v-slot:top>
    <div
      v-if="!isScreenWidthValid"
    >
      <v-col
        cols="12"
        class="text-right"
      >
        <span style="margin-right: 8px;">Announcement</span>
      </v-col>
    </div>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To insert content or text directly into the blank space above the mobile version of `v-data-table` in Vuetify 2, you can use the `v-data-table` slot named `header` in combination with the `v-slot` directive. Here's an example:

```html
<v-data-table
  :loading="loading"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
  disable-sort
  hide-default-footer
  class="elevation-1 mt-4 pt-4"
>
  <template v-slot:header>
    <div class="v-data-table-header v-data-table-header-mobile">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="v-data-table-header-mobile__wrapper">
            <span style="margin-right: 8px;">Announcement</span>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: I have tried, but the text will run into the first table, it is not at the top.